# To Disable CTRL+SHIFT+C in Google Chrome of Ubuntu?

Tags: google-chrome, usability, dvorak

This keybinding is very irritating because it is very close to the copy-command <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.
Partially, the problem can be explained by my keyboard layout Dvorak such that the browser may consider the keybinds as <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>.

How can you disable the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> binding in Google Chrome?

Comment: There are things of Google Chrome which make me prefer it over Firefox, such as the fact that it outperforms it and the "Duplicate" feature for the tab which I couldn't live without, however some things are just a hassle to deal with, such as this and the unrelocatable notifications. I think you'll need an extension for that.

Comment: Just right-click the tab you want to duplicate and select "Duplicate" from the drop-down menu

Comment: Can you disable this binding in Chromium?

Comment: I don't think so, it should be the same. Also I can't even find an extension to change the default shortcuts. I suggest you to try your luck here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/shortcut?_category=extensions

Answer (score 1):

I was able to successfully override the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> shortcut by using the [Shortcut Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortcut-manager/mgjjeipcdnnjhgodgjpfkffcejoljijf/related?hl=en-US) plugin and creating a new shortcut for the key combination.

You can then reassign it to trigger a host of pre-configured actions, or any javascript / bookmarklet code of your choosing. I don't really have any experience with javascript, so I can't really figure out how to make it act like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, but as far simply preventing it from bringing up the Developer Tools console, simply setting it to execute:

```
<script></script>
```

seems to work.

### EDIT

I since found that there ***is***, in fact, a simple way to copy to the clipboard in javascript, so instead of setting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to an empty script, set it to:

```
document.execCommand('copy');
```

or simply use Shortcut Manager's "Import Settings" feature and paste the following:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @ShortcutManager
// @name Override Ctrl+Shift+c
// @namespace FSBQ9ZTetyiG
// @key Ctrl+Shift+c
// @include *
// ==/UserScript==
document.execCommand('copy');
```

Comment: Outstanding idea! Do you have any idea how to do this without a plugin? This would be the ultimate goal.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. As far as I could find, there doesn't seem to be any way of modifying the pre-configured key-bindings. There may be a way to do so via the developer version.

Comment: l really would like to get a one-liner to make this change. I think it can be possible. Is it?